Delete all exe files in AppSwitched
Can someone help me what is wrong here? This is bat file. I want all *.exe files to be deleted there.
My code:
REG DELETE "HKEY_USERS\%usersid%\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FeatureUsage\AppSwitched\*.exe" /f 


As you have seen, the Delete method of reg.exe, does not accept wildcards. For this reason you would have to first enumerate the values, then identify those which end with the case insensitive string .exe.
I would advise that you at least get some assistance from PowerShell in identifying each of those values for deletion.
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "RegRoot=HKCU"
Set "RegKey=\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FeatureUsage\AppSwitched"

For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command
 "(Get-ItemProperty -Path '%RegRoot%:%RegKey%').PSObject.Properties"
 " | Where-Object Name -Match '\.exe$' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name"
 2^>NUL') Do %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Delete "%RegRoot%%RegKey%" /V "%%G" /F 1>NUL

As you can see, I have specifically performed this task for the Current User HKCU. If you really have multiple profiles already unlocked in the registry, and have sufficient permissions to access that key within each of them, you would need to change line 4. to use HKU and line 5. to prepend the relevant \S-I-D string(s). I will add however, that you should not be removing that data from other peoples' registries.

You've mentioned: I will add however, that you should not be removing that data from other peoples' registries.
Is it dangerous to do so? I thought it was like clearing the exe history files from regedit. Why i shouldnt use it?

That particular registry key provides the number of times your .exe files switched focus, i.e. were left-clicked on the taskbar. Whilst it could be used foresically to see the names and locations of your GUI application executables, that information is not what I'd deem a security issue. Also the amount of space taken by that key's data is negligible with regard to your drive space. Whilst you are free to delete it, and have new data added again, there is no good reason to believe that all other user account holders on your system need this too. Let them decide, don't force it on them.
